# NHibernate: Convert Guid to string in query

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate with Linq or Criterion, is it possible to do a LIKE query on a GUID column?

In T-SQL this is easy:  *select * from mytable where id like '0ae%'*

NHibernate won't convert the Guid to a string though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer - I need to use projections. Here's what I came up with:

```
var query = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (MyClass))
    .Add(Restrictions.Like(
        Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Id")),
        '%'+keywords+"%"));
```