# Select Guid range in NHibernate where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to select range of Guids with NHibernate:

```
 customersToUpdate =
                    Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                           .Where(x => x.SyncEndpointTick > localTick && x.SyncEndpointTick <= endTick).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Asc
                           .Where(x=> x.Id.ToString().ToLower() > lastResultId.ToString().ToLower())
                           .ConvertTo<List<Customer>>();
```

The problem is that LINQ does not allow me to compare Guids:

```
.Where(x=> x.Id.ToString().ToLower() > lastResultId.ToString().ToLower())
```

Thank you all

Comment: You code is comparing strings, not GUIDs, although the comparison operators are also not defined for GUIDs, because they don't make much sense there either.

Comment: I know i am comparing strings, but there is no other way of comparing Guids. I am looking for alternative or how can I do this the right way

Comment: you could count the processed records and use Skip(processed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436762/1236044) you may try to replace this line :

```
.Where(x=> x.Id.ToString().ToLower() > lastResultId.ToString().ToLower())
```

with :

```
.Where(Restrictions
        .Gt(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Id")),
            lastResultId.ToString()).IgnoreCase())
```

Depending on your db collation, the `IgnoreCase` might be useless.

Hope this will help